# Way to split big class and fix chain inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

I had a big class, `Admin`, which had too many separate methods with different functionality and calls to a database and it was getting quite hard to manage, so I decided to split it, but now `Admin` is somewhat useless. I want to have `Admin` inherit all the smaller classes but the only way I can think of is through chain inheritance like so:

```
public class Admin extends A {
//code in here
}

public class A extends B {
//code in here
}

public class B extends C {
//code in here
}
```

None of the methods that are in B are used in A, but I want to use them in Admin. It feels like bad practice, but I don't know how to implement it in another way.

Is there a way to better create this class, without having to put every method from the classes in `Admin`

Comment: Consider [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Do not use [inheritance as a means to achieve code re-use](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/why-avoid-java-inheritance-extends).

Answer (score 0):

If you have cross-object behavior, which is not inherited through the current inheritance tree, you should isolate (decouple) this behavior from the tree, and make it inject-able according to needs. You can start by defining an interface which describes these behaviors and implement it whenever a particular object has a these.

For instance you can have:

```
public interface Capable{
  public void doThis();
  public void doThat();
}
```

And say B should have this behavior specification but not A, you can just do:

```
public class B extends A implements Capable {
  //some other stuff
  public void doThis(){..}
  public void doThat(){..}
}
```